# How can I detach a tab from my main chrome window (into a new window)?

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, window

I want to be able to move the current tab from the window (with other tabs) to a new window, in the foreground, keeping all other tabs open. I'm using Google Chrome, always up to date, on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

I'm happy for a script / extension / similar.

Bear in mind I have a number of windows open (maybe 3 or 4).

It can't be closing and reopening the tab because I may have unsaved details (e.g. I'm taking a screenshot of the typed content).

Comment: are you against drag and drop?

Comment: @NewUSer if you can automate it, that's fine. For me, drag and drop is a little buggy (it can take a number of attempts) and it also interrupts my keyboard focused workflow.

Comment: Take a look at these: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-window-keyboard-sh/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh and http://www.getferro.com/

Comment: @Zacharee1 that has been posted. http://askubuntu.com/a/625709/186134 Thanks for the second one.

Comment: Oh, hehe. Did the second one help?

Comment: @Zacharee1 That. Looks. Cool :P

Comment: So...? I don't know what you mean. Does it satisfy what you need?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I don't think it solves it, but it looks cool - I'm gonna use it for other stuffs :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [Tab To Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-window-keyboard-sh/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh/related?hl=en-GB) extension of chrome. it will provide you several shortcuts to manage your tabs.

For example, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to move the active tab to a new window.

The shortcuts are customisable.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! In addition to just detaching the current tab to a separate window, the windows are also automatically organised side-by-side. Very cool!

Answer (score 15):

In case someone is interested in a current solution without extensions:

If you just start typing the name of the website you want to access or highlight the URL and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, a new detached window will open.

Comment: I use Ctrl+L to jump to address bar, then hit Shift+Return to open in new window.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You can also hit `Ctrl+N` and start typing the URL or search into the new window.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I can't live without [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) as it lets me do so much more than just move tabs.

You can easily open a tab into a new window with <kbd>W</kbd> or you can search across all your open tabs (in all windows) with <kbd>T</kbd> or open a url from your history with <kbd>O</kbd>. If you were editing text in an input field you may need to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> first to "unselect" the field, but that is common with "modal" editors like Vim which Vimium borrows many of its ideas and key mappings from.

A new tab is just a <kbd>t</kbd> away as well.

Sadly it doesn't have any direct "send tab to a specific window" options like Tab to Window (or at least the version I used to use on Firefox allowed that), but it sounds like you don't need that.

For actually moving tabs to organize them I use the extension [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) which works great and lets you "tag" windows and tabs with notes, and the BEST feature is that you can simply hit <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> to save out the entire list of tabs to send via email or backup with Dropbox/Drive/etc.

Comment: I use Vimium, and I didn't know about the `W` this is good thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension called [Tab Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-manager/coonecdghnepgiblpccbbihiahajndda?hl=en)

Install it and easily you can do what you want

[image]

When you click on + as shown in the picture this will detach the current tab to a new window

Comment: For me the + creates a new window. It's better that trying to drag, so +1 but it is some quite precise mouse control needed, so I'd like to see if I get another answer.

Comment: @Tim I'll wait with you, a bash script or terminal command  will be amazing. i like to know if there is such method

Answer (score 3):

Press F6 which selects the search/url field then press it again which would select the tab, then  press shift+F10 (which is right click) from there select the second option "move tab to new window" and from there select "new window".